# Disable Buttons in HTML5 or Javascript or Jquery, so that any hacker cannot alter the state by Inspecting the button and changing its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

How Can Buttons be disabled in HTML5 or Javascript or Jquery, so that any hacker cannot alter the state by Inspecting the button and changing its value?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: link helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9679381/965146

Comment: A "hacker" can always make his browser show him anything.

Comment: Shutdown your server. It's the only way to be sure a hacker cannot press a button.

Comment: you just cannot. If you fear about state values, this is the very reason you never trust a user input, and delegate dangerous code to the server side. Of course, the server wants to check if all state values are correct before doing anything

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do anything client-side (i.e., disable button via JavaScript) to prevent the hacker from altering the state. More to the fact, you don't need to worry about whether or not a hacker can alter the state of the button. The most important thing you should do is perform server-side validation to prevent any hacker from doing something you don't want them to do (i.e., perform unwanted READ/WRITE operations to a database) when a hacker might try to enable a disabled button to submit a form, for example.